# Flutter different behaviour in debug vs release mode

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

I'm developing these features for a flutter app: loading an image from gallery, resize and save it.

The resizing part is a cpu intensive operation so I followed the approach suggested [here](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples) using isolate to gain a better user experience.

When I run the code in debug mode I have no issue, but when I try the same code in release mode my image is saved in a [wrong way](https://github.com/KiraDiShira/flutterRedux/blob/master/lib/src/localizations/profile.png).

Can someone help me to undestand the issue I explained please?

I test the code only on this device: HUAWEI P9 lite VNS-L31 with android 7.0

Here is the code to replicate the problem. This is a new flutter project with the following files:

In `pubspec.yaml` I add this section:

```
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  image_picker: ^0.4.10
  image: ^2.0.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

All code is in `lib/main.dart`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  File _file;

  Future<File> _getImage() async {
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      return image;
    }
    return null;
  }

  static decode(DecodeParam param) async {
    var p = await param.file.readAsBytes();
    var image = decodeImage(p);
    var thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120);
    param.sendPort.send(thumbnail);
  }

  void _displayImage() async {
    setState(() {
      _file = null;
    });

    File file = await _getImage();
    ReceivePort receivePort = new ReceivePort();

    await Isolate.spawn(decode, new DecodeParam(file, receivePort.sendPort));

    var image = await receivePort.first;

    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;

    File profilePictureFile =
        File(p.join(tempPath, 'thumbnail' + _counter.toString() + '.png'))
          ..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(image));

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      _file = profilePictureFile;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _file != null
                ? Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    width: 200.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, image: FileImage(_file))))
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _displayImage,
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DecodeParam {
  final File file;
  final SendPort sendPort;
  DecodeParam(this.file, this.sendPort);
}
```

`flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v0.9.7-pre.61, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.15063], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 0.9.7-pre.61 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 2d81adf74c (2 days ago), 2018-10-05 22:29:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 572fa5646a
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.6.0.flutter-c6254163dc

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
    • Android SDK at d:\Profiles\alarosa\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 26.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
    • VS Code at d:\Profiles\alarosa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.19.0

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.27.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.19.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • HUAWEI VNS L31 • 4TE0216A14001341 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: What emulators or devices did you test this with? Is this also on Android or only on iOS?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I test the code only on this device: HUAWEI P9 lite VNS-L31 with android 7.0

Comment: Could be a Flutter/Dart bug or an issue in your code (for example timing-related). If it's not a Flutter bug, then it's probably an issue with `copyResize(image, 120);` but the code is missing in your question.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer I post in my question all the code to replicate the issue. The `copyResize` method is visible thanks to this `import 'package:image/image.dart'; `. I edited my question to add information about the dependencies added in  `pubspec.yaml` file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please create an issue in github.com/flutter/flutter. Please check if it still reproduces in `master` channel before reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @GunterZochbauer suggestion I opened [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22796) on flutter repository.

Flutter team is working on it, and, as you can read on github thread, Jason-Simmons suggest the following work around.

Change the sender to:

```
param.sendPort.send([thumbnail.width, thumbnail.height, thumbnail.data]);
```

and the receiver to:

```
List<dynamic> imageData = await receivePort.first;
var image = new Image.fromBytes(imageData[0], imageData[1], imageData[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `writeAsBytesSync` method have a params `flush`, default value is false.

The comment of `flush`: If the [flush] argument is set to true data written will be flushed to the file system before returning.

Edit your code to next:

```dart
File profilePictureFile =
        File(p.join(tempPath, 'thumbnail' + _counter.toString() + '.png'))
          ..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(image), flush: true);
```

Check to see if there have been changes.

Non-isolated has memory sharing. If it is isolated, the file need to read the file system, and the file content may not have been written or only half.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar but with displaying images, by removing the expanded it fixed the behaviour.